# Java string connection

Tags: java, string

can anyone tell me how can i connect one string with a group of strings and each string have certain value.
for exampe:

```
String car = new String()
//i give it a value of say 10 dollars
and then i have this group of Strings/Objects
for example:
String frontWindow = new String()
//i set a value for it
String backWindow = new String()
//i set a value for it
String wheel = new String()
//i set a value for it
```

And i want to calculate the sum of the car with some or all of the string above.I thought about usint the print method but then i would be able to choose only all strings.So does anyone know how can i make this work in the console output?

Comment: You need to format your question better.  I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @tkcsam you and me both.

Comment: Your approach is not even close to what you are trying to do. Why do these have to be strings? Why not just integers or, better yet, a class? Please follow a tutorial and come back with an actual issue.

Comment: basicaly it is a calculator with one base string-"car" and a few sub string so to speak,each one have value.the user have to choose the string car of course and some or all of the string below it and calculate the total sum,but how to connect the base string with the rest ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "connect"; do you mean concatenate strings? Are you manipulating the values of these strings somewhere?

Comment: ok then if they ate integers,or better  double  how do i connect them

Comment: the values are not changable

Answer (score 2):

That's not very clear, but it seems like you want to make a Car class and access variables inside of it.

```
public class Car{
    public String frontWindow, wheel;

    public Car(String frontWindow, String wheel){
        this.frontWindow = frontWindow;
        this.wheel = wheel
    }
}
```

then, from inside an other class you can access it like this:

```
Car myCar = new Car("this is my front window", "this is my wheel");
System.out.println(myCar.wheel);
```

if you want those variables to hold values instead of strings, make them "double"s or "int"s.

Look up the difference between storing Strings (text) and Numbers (int, double, long, float, etc.)

Also look up [Object Oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) for how that all works. Try a google search for "how to create a new object in java", or something like that. Then you also might be able to use getters and setters for those variables you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine strings like so:

```
String totalSum = car + frontWindow + backWindow + wheel;
```

However, given this example:

```
String car = "10.00";
String frontWindow = "2.00";
String backWindow = "2.00";
String wheel = "1.00";
```

They would add together end-to-end and be like so: `"10.002.002.001.00"`

`int` and `double` are actually meant to have number operations done to them instead of `String`.

```
int i = 5; // int's are whole numbers, no decimals allowed
int j = 3;
int total = i + j; //Total is 8
double d1 = 1.1;
double d2 = 2.5;
double dTotal = d1 + d2; //Total is 3.6
```

You can still print them out to the console by doing `System.out.println(dTotal);`

Probably out of scope, but if you plan on dealing with money in a serious business app, you should check into the `BigDecimal` class because of tiny rounding errors that can occur with `doubles` and `floats`.